# Counting number of printed lines in console Python

Tags: python, terminal, count, console

Is there a way to count the number of printed lines in the console without some variable that would be "manually" incremented at every input or output?

I want to count the number of lines printed till now on the terminal window.

For example:

```py
import os

os.system("clear")

# os.system("cls") on windows

for i in range(10):
  print("Line: ", i)

# function that prints some more lines and I don't know the number
printSomeMoreLines()  

# call some function here to return the number of lines printed in
# the terminal window so far 
print(someFunctionToReturnTheNumberOfLinesPrintedInTheTerminalSoFar())
```

Comment: More details are needed for a good answer. Which console to you mean--CPython's, IPython, Jupyter, or other? Do you consider a long printed line that wraps to the next line to be one or more than one line?

Comment: Oh, I was thinking on terminal, like cmd or bash... I would consider it more then one line.

Comment: In general, on SE sites, the more thorough and detailed your question, the better the answer(s). If you don't provide details, then the answerers have to guess and will likely not answer the question you really want answered... Here is some additional information: http://stackoverflow.com/tour

Comment: @nicorellius I understand that, BUT in past when ever I posted detailed question it was closed within 2 minutes... I think that people didn't even read it...

Comment: @Newbie My apologies for coming off weird... I totally understand. Sometimes users around here can be aggressive. Hang in there ;-)

Comment: @nicorellius No problem mate :D I guess that experience is needed even when posting questions here.

Answer (score 1):

Something like this might work (using pipe and the word count command with number of lines, `wc -l`):

`python -c "import sys; print('\n'.join(sys.path))" | wc -l`

This gives `10` for my system...

Obviously, this is a Unix command. For Windows, you could try something like this:

https://superuser.com/questions/959036/what-is-the-windows-equivalent-of-wc-l#959037

Comment: Yea, but that won't work on different platforms, do you know command prompt equivalent for wc?

Comment: You didn't specify any details, so I just sort of stabbed at it... You could try something like this: http://superuser.com/questions/959036/what-is-the-windows-equivalent-of-wc-l#959037

Comment: So there is no way to do that with some Python feature except os.system(command) trick? Maybe writing some function that will increment counter when ever \n occurs...